# How we transform a parametric equation having trigonometric functions into the cartesian form?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I have the following parametric curve:

- $x(t)=\frac{3t^2\cos(t)+4\pi^2\cos\frac{t^3}{4\pi^2}}{4\pi^2+3t^2}$
- $y(t)=\frac{3t^2\sin(t)+4\pi^2\sin\frac{t^3}{4\pi^2}}{4\pi^2+3t^2}$

Is it possible to obtain a cartesian (polynomial-like) form in $x$ and $y$ from the above-given parametric form? An attempt using Matlab produced an "groebner::eliminate" error. The use of any tool or tool combination (Mathematica, Matlab, Maple, Maxima) is welcome.

The curve looks as follows:

[image: parametric plot of the curve]

Comment: I find myself wondering whether you could get anything going with combinations of $x, y, x^{\prime}$, and $y^{\prime}$. When you differentiate sums of sines and cosines, sometimes cross-terms cancel and you can do a lot of Pythagorean magic. Of course, then you'd have a system of non-linear DE's to solve.

Comment: Just thinking out loud ... The substitution $t\to 2\pi u$ gives this slightly-more-readable (to me) form: $$(x,y) = \frac{ 3 u^2 (\cos2\pi u, \sin2\pi u)+ (\cos2\pi u^3,\sin2\pi u^3)}{3 u^2+1}$$ I can't say I'd be optimistic about finding a Cartesian form; certainly not a "nice" one. (Arguably, Cartesian forms are *rarely* as nice as parametrics; besides, parametrics include path-tracing information that Cartesians lack, making them more useful.) What are you ultimately hoping to learn about this curve?

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful hints. The substitution of @Blue is elegant. Why I am interested in the polynomial form? I would like to know the degree of that curve. But you are right - parametric forms have obviously their advantages too.